# which.max ties method in R

Tags: r, max, min

`which.max` and `which.min` will return the smallest index of the max or min value if there are ties.

Is there a way around this so that the largest index is returned **without** affecting the efficiency of the function?

`max.col` has this exact functionality, but I am dealing with a vector not a matrix.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
x<-c(1,2,1,4,3,4)
#identical to which.max, except returns all indices with max
which(x==max(x)) 
[1] 4 6
z<-which(x==max(x))
z[length(z)]
[1] 6
#or with tail
tail(which(x==max(x)),1)
[1] 6
```

edit:

Or, you could also use `max.col` function for vectors like this:

```
max.col(t(x),"last")
[1] 6
#or
max.col(matrix(x,nrow=1),"last")
[1] 6
```

edit: Some benchmarking:

```
x<-sample(1:1000,size=10000,replace=TRUE)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(which.max(x),{z<-which(x==max(x));z[length(z)]}, 
     tail(which(x==max(x)),1),max.col(matrix(x,nrow=1),"last"),
     max.col(t(x),"last"),which.max(rev(x)),times=1000)
Unit: microseconds
                                             expr     min      lq  median      uq       max neval
                                     which.max(x)  29.390  30.323  30.323  31.256 17550.276  1000
 {     z <- which(x == max(x))     z[length(z)] }  40.586  42.452  42.919  44.318   631.178  1000
                      tail(which(x == max(x)), 1)  57.380  60.646  61.579  64.844   596.657  1000
             max.col(matrix(x, nrow = 1), "last") 134.353 138.085 139.485 144.383   710.949  1000
                            max.col(t(x), "last") 116.159 119.425 121.291 125.956   729.610  1000
                                which.max(rev(x))  89.569  91.435  92.368  96.566   746.404  1000
```

So all methods seem to be slower than the original (which gives wrong result), but `z <- which(x == max(x));z[length(z)]` seems to be fastest option of these.

Comment: Benchmarking is beautiful! Thank you, I think I'll go with option 2! ` z <- which(x == max(x))     z[length(z)]`

Answer (score 9):

You could reverse `x`

```
which.max(rev(x))
which.min(rev(x))
```

Answer (score 5):

The `which` function has an 'arr.ind' parameter normally set to FALSE but usefully set to TRUE in this case:

```
x <- sample(1:20, 50, repl=TRUE)

> which(x==max(x), arr.ind=TRUE)
[1] 11 23
> tail(which(x==max(x), arr.ind=TRUE) , 1)
[1] 23
```

Using the arr.ind argument is particularly useful with matrix or array structures, but it does work with atomic vectors as well.

Comment: DWin, is there a difference in setting `arr.ind=TRUE` for vectors?

Comment: I don't think so. I probably should just have used `which`. Sometimes I over-think.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Jouni's answer, you could instead use `max` on the result of `which`:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4)
which(x == max(x)) 
[1] 4 6
max(which(x == max(x)))
[1] 6
```

Benchmarking:

```
x <- sample(1:1000, size = 10000, replace = TRUE)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(which.max(x), {z <- which(x == max(x)); z[length(z)]}, 
               tail(which(x == max(x)), 1), max.col(matrix(x, nrow = 1), "last"),
               max.col(t(x), "last"), which.max(rev(x)), max(which(x == max(x))), times = 1000)
Unit: microseconds
                                             expr     min      lq       mean  median      uq      max neval
                                     which.max(x)   6.322   6.717   7.171838   7.112   7.112   40.297  1000
 {     z <- which(x == max(x))     z[length(z)] }  27.260  28.445  37.126964  28.840  29.630 2276.346  1000
                      tail(which(x == max(x)), 1)  35.952  37.927  45.198484  38.718  40.298 1005.038  1000
             max.col(matrix(x, nrow = 1), "last") 160.791 162.766 181.698171 163.557 169.087 1688.494  1000
                            max.col(t(x), "last")  84.149  86.124 100.249921  86.915  89.680 1230.618  1000
                                which.max(rev(x))  53.729  55.310  69.442985  56.100  57.680 1076.149  1000
                          max(which(x == max(x)))  26.865  27.655  35.552256  28.050  28.841 1029.137  1000
```