# Return the value from one column based on the max value in another column

Tags: r

I thought this would be easy but I'm hitting a wall. Very simply, I'd like to return the value in V2 based on the max value in V1. If there's a tie in the V1 max values it would "randomly" pick one and return the V2 value.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
set.seed(1)
DF <- matrix(sample(1:40,40),ncol=2,nrow=20)
DF <- as.data.frame.matrix(DF)
View(DF)
```

Comment: `DF$V1[which.max(DF$V2)]`

Comment: I would say `DF$V1[max.col(t(DF$V2))]` instead since `max.col` has a ties argument (the default is random) but `which.max` does not; [similar question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630032/which-max-ties-method-in-r)

Comment: The example does not have the desired output that should result from `DF`

Comment: @rawr          Thanks to everyone responding back! Because of possible ties I'll try the max.col code.